# React Native Tab navigation from a button group

Tags: react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

In React Native, I have a button group that I want controlling some tabs using Tab Navigation.

The tab pages all have `tabBarVisible: false` and I want to move to the correct tab page by calling `navigate('screen1')` etc. But inside my `updateTab` called from the button group's `onpress` I cannot access the `navigation.navigate` function.

What can I do?

```
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const Tabpage = TabNavigator(
{
   tab1: {
     screen: screen1,
     navigationOptions: {
     tabBarVisible: false,
     tabBarLabel: 'Screen 1'
  }, ...
}

export default class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabIndex: 2
    };
    this.updateTabIndex = this.updateTabIndex.bind(this);
  }

   updateTabIndex = tabIndex => {
     console.log(tabIndex);
     this.setState({ tabIndex });
     switch (tabIndex) {
        case 0:
           console.log('nearby chosen');
           // navigate('screen1'); // error:  no function named navigate
           // navigation.navigate('screen1'); // error: not a function
           // this.navigate or this.navigation.navigate all fail too  
           break;
       case 1: // etc.
       default: // etc. 
     }
  }   

  render() {
    <View style={styles.tabsview}>
      <ButtonGroup
        containerBorderRadius={40}
        selectedBackgroundColor='#FF0000'
        onPress={ this.updateTabIndex }
        selectedIndex={this.state.tabIndex}
        buttons={['screen0', 'screen1', 'screen2']}
        containerStyle={{ height: 30 }}
      />
    </View>
```

How do I access the navigation from the changed state tab index?

Comment: Try this.props.navigation.navigate

Comment: thanks nami put it as your answer and I'll accept it. So now there is no error, but the page stays the same without the tab "navigating" to the next page. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your full tab navigator code and your button group code. That will help understand the problem.

Comment: Hope to get to it later today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.props.navigation.navigate('screen1');`